# elasticsearch query child list containing specific value

Tags: elasticsearch

I writing a query to return the products that has a specific promotionCode. In my index, product has following property indexed

```
"offers": [
   {
        "promotionCode": "MV"
   },
   {
        "promotionCode": "LI"
   },
   .....
]
```

My initial thought the following would be the answer to

```
GET alias-live-dev/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
        "offers.promotionCode":"MV"
    }
  }
}
```

However, this always return 0 hit, I am guessing, it failed because offers is a list. Could anyone please advise what would the right query for this scenario. Thanks in advance.

In mapping,

```
  "productId": {
    "type": "keyword"
  },
  "offers": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
```

......

```
"promotionCode": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
```

Comment: Looks good to me, worked fine when I tried as well. Can you check the mapping and post it here? What made you conclude that the offers list is the issue?

Comment: Not sure list is the cause. However, searching a product which has  promotionCode MV using productId does return.  I don't see why offers.promotionCode should not work

Comment: find the answer. The offers is nested, so query should use nested as well

Comment: can you post your answer here? It will be helpful for anybody else who runs into the same issue.